# Finding largest visible area inside polygon using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, viewshed

I need to find the largest possible visible area inside many polygons. The polygons represent clearcuts inside forests.

For example if I stand here I can see 10 out of 14 hectares, nowhere else can I stand to see more.

The workflow I can think of now is:

- Create a grid in each polygon

For each grid point:

- Draw line of sight-lines from each point in the grid to all vertices
- Intersect them with the polygon
- Select by location the lines intersecting current grid point
- Buffer - dissolve calculate area

This is going to take a long time.

Is there a tool for this?

[image]

To create sight lines:

```
polylyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygon')[0]
g = [f.geometry() for f in polylyr.getFeatures()][0]
verts = [v for v in g.vertices()]

pointlyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Grid')[0]
point = QgsPoint([f.geometry() for f in pointlyr.getSelectedFeatures()][0].asPoint())

linelist = []
for vert in verts:
    Line = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([vert, point])
    linelist.append(Line)

vl = QgsVectorLayer("LineString?crs={}&index=yes".format(pointlyr.crs().authid()), "myLayer", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

for L in linelist:
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(L)
    provider.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

Comment: Have you think about use grass r.viewshed (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.viewshed.html) ? My idea is to create an elevation raster from your polygon (no polygon = elevation), compute the viewshed and polygonize the result.

Comment: I have no solution on the top of my finger, but you could first test if your polygons are convex. A convex polygon can be fully "seen" from anywhere inside itself, so you can skip the calculation. Otherwise, I think that the solution must be visible inside from the largest included rectangle, which could also save some processing time

Comment: You are basically searching for the widest interior section of polygon and build the largest possible polygon (circle) from there (the midpoint of the widest interior). JTS already provides such construction as described in this blog: [Martin Davis](http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2020/04/maximum-inscribed-circle-and-largest.html)

Comment: The routine also ported to GEOS (>= 3.9.0) and to Postgis as ST_MaximumInscribedCircle: [Paul Ramsey](https://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2020/06/developer-life-2.html). I'm not familiar with pyqgis. But looking at your snapshot, i'm pretty sure that those links will lead you to what you want

Comment: I might be overthinking this but I don't think maximum inscribed circle will always be right Is that different than pole of inaccessibility? These papers looks interesting https://www.researchgate.net/publication/249009356_Towards_a_mixed_approach_combining_visibility_and_mobility_studies_to_analyze_the_Eleftheria_Square_Nicosia_CY https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/160/1/turner-doxa-osullivan-penn-2001.pdf

Comment: The largest inscribed circle wont be correct. Isovist graph, that is a good word to google, thanks

Comment: QGIS plugin https://github.com/SpaceGroupUCL/qgisSpaceSyntaxToolkit on top of depthmapX that implements the "isovist" (https://github.com/SpaceGroupUCL/depthmapX or https://github.com/varoudis/depthmapX not sure of official repo)?

Comment: In terms of lakes the longest straight line you can create is called a fetch. Searching the internet for this term throws up various works where they have calculated the fetch

Answer (score 2):

I know that the title says with PyQGIS but, you can solve just using some tools. In case this is valid for you, then you can make a model and correct it via python or iterate it over your polygons.

1. You need a DEM of you polygon/layer extension. Dont't worry. If you don't have it, just create one using the v.to.rast tool and assign a value of 0 to the cells.
2. Execute Visibility index (awesome tool from the plugin Visibility Analysis) and interpret the results. As you can see in the image, lighter areas are the ones where more outgoing intervisibility.
3. Transform the raster to points and select the one with the highest value (here I've selected three just to check validity process).
4. Execute a Viewshed with that point (I'm doing it with three points just for testing).
5. Get the area of it just from "raster statistics" (the sum will be the quantity of raster cells with visibility what you can then transform into area knowing the resolution) or you can also "poligonize" the result and then calculate the area with the attributes calculator. If you want a smoother result, perform a simplification of the poligon.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You can find the complete sequence of analysis (with checking the validity of the tools): https://youtu.be/xnU7ICwpRTU

Comment: What are the values of your DEM, 0 inside and ? outside the polygon? Are you using Incoming or Outgoing views?

Comment: Inside 0 (for flat surface) and "no data" outside.